# I remove last item and data target its own the carousel-control dose not work.

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-carousel

I have Bootstrap Carousel as shown below

It works fine as it is but when I remove last item and data target its own
the carousel-control dose not work. What could be the issue here, any help please? Thanks....

```
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#bootstrap-touch-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#bootstrap-touch-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#bootstrap-touch-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper For Slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

            <!-- Third Slide -->
            <div class="item active">

                <!-- Slide Background -->
                <img src="image/slide1.jpeg" alt="Bootstrap Touch Slider"  class="slide-image"/>
                <div class="bs-slider-overlay"></div>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- Slide Text Layer -->
                        <div class="slide-text slide_style_left">
                            <h1 data-animation="animated zoomInRight">Bootstrap Carousel</h1>
                            <p data-animation="animated fadeInLeft">Bootstrap carousel now touch enable slide.</p>
                            <a href="http://bootstrapthemes.co/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" data-animation="animated fadeInLeft">select one</a>
                            <a href="http://bootstrapthemes.co/" target="_blank"  class="btn btn-primary" data-animation="animated fadeInRight">select two</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End of Slide -->

            <!-- Second Slide -->
            <div class="item">

                <!-- Slide Background -->
                <img src="image/slide2.jpeg" alt="Bootstrap Touch Slider"  class="slide-image"/>
                <div class="bs-slider-overlay"></div>
                <!-- Slide Text Layer -->
                <div class="slide-text slide_style_center">
                    <h1 data-animation="animated flipInX">Bootstrap touch slider</h1>
                    <p data-animation="animated lightSpeedIn">Make Bootstrap Better together.</p>
                    <a href="http://bootstrapthemes.co/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" data-animation="animated fadeInUp">select one</a>
                    <a href="http://bootstrapthemes.co/" target="_blank"  class="btn btn-primary" data-animation="animated fadeInDown">select two</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End of Slide -->

            <!-- Third Slide -->
            <div class="item">

                <!-- Slide Background -->
                <img src="image/slide3.jpeg" alt="Bootstrap Touch Slider"  class="slide-image"/>
                <div class="bs-slider-overlay"></div>
                <!-- Slide Text Layer -->
                <div class="slide-text slide_style_right">
                    <h1 data-animation="animated zoomInLeft">Beautiful Animations</h1>
                    <p data-animation="animated fadeInRight">Lots of css3 Animations to make slide beautiful .</p>
                    <a href="http://bootstrapthemes.co/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" data-animation="animated fadeInLeft">select one</a>
                    <a href="http://bootstrapthemes.co/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" data-animation="animated fadeInRight">select two</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- End of Slide -->


        </div><!-- End of Wrapper For Slides -->

        <!-- Right Control -->

        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-touch-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>

        <!-- Left Control -->

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#bootstrap-touch-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>


    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- slider -->
```

It works fine as it is but when I remove last item and data target its own
the carousel-control dose not work. What could be the issue here, any help please? Thanks....